# can i ask using useEffect inside onFocus Event?

Tags: reactjs

```
 const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);
 const [inputHover, setInputHover] = useState(false);
```

...

```
 <div className={`search ${showSearch ? "show-search" : ""} `}>
            <button
              onFocus={
                setShowSearch(true)
              }
              onBlur={() => {
                if (!inputHover) {
                  return setShowSearch(false);
                }
              }}
            >
```

First I'm using just useState but

```
[Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.]
```

this error occurred
so I wrapped it inside useEffect then
[Warning: Expected `onFocus` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.]
I find this error children component receives props but just direct push event function

so.. finally upside code is complete...
but this code does not work.
help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Expected onFocus listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type` occurred because you tried to pass an object as an event handler instead of a function. You should pass a function as the event handler to avoid this error. So `onFocus={ ()=> setShowSearch(true) }` is the right way to do it.

`[Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.]` appeared because you called `setShowSearch(true)` in `onFocus` handler and every time when button rendered `setShowSearch(true)` executed and changed the state and it triggered another rerender and and `setShowSearch(true)` executed again and so it went on endlessly. When you put it in a callback form like `onFocus={ ()=> setShowSearch(true)}` it only gets executed when you focus the button

Answer (score 1):

onFocus={ ()=> setShowSearch(true) }

i fixed right now.

but i didn't know why this code work no error.

who tell me why that code dosen't work and this code work?